# Alternative to chrome.socket for chrome extension?

Tags: google-chrome-extension, tcp

I'm trying to make a chrome extension that can exchange data with other users on the same network, but unfortunately chrome.socket.tcp has been deprecated and I can't find an alternative. I don't want to use any third party services to funnel data and don't want to rewrite it for node.

https://developer.chrome.com/docs/apps/reference/sockets/tcp

I tried to add "sockets" to permissions in the manifest.json and the token was unrecognised.

Comment: There won't be chrome.sockets for extensions per https://crbug.com/40139747. Try WebRTC.